# Basic Bool function giving segmentation fault

Tags: c

So I'm trying to learn functions a bit better and be able to write one that is useful and in then one that is recursive and sorts a list of number given to the program. However I'm getting a segmentation fault here. I feel this is occuring when I try to read `argv[i+1]` when I have run out of entries in `argv[]`. However why doesn't my `if(i < argc){`statement checking this preclude this from happening?

Here's my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool compare(val1,val2)
{
    if(val1 > val2){return false;}
    else{return true;}
}

// int values[], int n
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        //print unsorted list
        printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
        if(i < argc){
            if(compare(*argv[i],*argv[i+1]))
            {
                printf("true\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("false\n");
            }


        }
        // Add else for odd numbered lists
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `i == argc - 1`, `argv[i + 1]` is undefined.

Comment: That was it, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[i+1]` is not defined if `i==argc-1`.

For example, if `argc=3` that means you are using two arguments (`argv[0]`, `argv[1]`, and `argv[2]` are defined). You are trying to access `argv[3]` when you call `argv[i+1]` when `i` is equal to `2`.

All you have to do is to redefine your `for` and remove `if(i < argc)`.

Your code may look like this:

```
for(int i=1; i < argc-1; i++){
    //print unsorted list
    printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
    if(compare(*argv[i],*argv[i+1]))
        printf("true\n");
    else
        printf("false\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> why doesn't my `if(i < argc){`statement checking this preclude this
>   from happening?

This statement allows the code to continue if i is less than argc, the argument count. Let's say you have three arguments, i is allowed to proceed at a value of 2 or less.

In the very next line you try to access argv[i+1]. We've established i could be 2, so you're trying to access an item at index 3. It's 0 indexed and there are 3 items (0, 1, 2), so you're trying to access an item that doesn't exist.

```
if(compare(*argv[i],*argv[i+1]))
```